Laravel Does not work on specific route only
i using laravel 11 , everything in the project works well, but only two routes in the project not work
(`127.0.0.1:8000/educator` and `127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard`).
and there are no routes similar in the project.
when i try those routes, i got 404, but not the default laravel 404 pagei i got diffrent 404 page.
laravel default 404 page:

404 that i got:

i try the same route with another views and with diffrent controllers and stay not work,
even like this not work:
Route::get('/educator', function () {
    return 'This is a test route';
});

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home.index');
})->name('home');


Route::get('/educator', function () {
    return 'This is a test route';
});

Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return 'This is a test route';
});

/******************************** AUTH ROUTES *******************************/

Route::get('login', [AuthController::class, 'showLogin'])->name('login');
Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
Route::get('register', [AuthController::class, 'showRegistration'])->name('register');
Route::post('register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);


Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {

    /******************************** STUDENT ROUTES *******************************/

Route::get('learning', [IndexController::class, 'learning'])->name('learning');
    Route::post('logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');

    /******************************** COURSE ROUTES *******************************/

    Route::get('course', [CourseController::class, 'course'])->name('course');
    Route::get('course/lecture', [CourseController::class, 'lecture'])->name('lecture');
    Route::get('course/lecture/video', [CourseController::class, 'lecture_video'])->name('lecture-video');
    Route::get('course/lecture/text', [CourseController::class, 'lecture_text'])->name('lecture-text');
    Route::get('course/lecture/resource', [CourseController::class, 'lecture_resource'])->name('lecture-resource');
    Route::get('course/lecture/material', [CourseController::class, 'lecture_material'])->name('lecture-material');
    Route::get('course/lecture/survey', [CourseController::class, 'lecture_survey'])->name('lecture-survey');

});


.htaccess:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>



all routes in my web.php work, except "/educator" and "/dashboard"
i also try diffrent broswers and diffrent servers (laragon and xampp) i tried to the project again, but still not works.
pls is there any one can help me to fix this problem.

php artisan route:listcheck if the route is present. Then do php artisan route:clear.

it was in the list , but still not works

post your web.php in order

In xampp mod rewrite is disabled by default. You can follow this tutorial to enable: https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/how-to-enable-mod_rewrite-in-xampp-wamp/

Can you give an example of an url that does work?

I enabled mod rewrite before actually.

Can you post your .htaccess?

Route::get('course', [CourseController::class, 'course'])->name('course');
Route::get('course/lecture', [CourseController::class, 'lecture'])->name('lecture');
all routes in web.php work, except "/educator" and "/dashboard"

Please do not post code and more information in comments, it's extremely hard to read. Instead, [edit] your post and add that information there.

Do you have anything in your public folder that's related to dashboard or educator? You might also want to check the apache logs to see if there's any hints there

thanks brothers, the problem was because of the folders that have the same name in public folder, as @aynber said.

There were two files (educator, dashboard) with the same route name in the public folder.
so i rename the folders and clear the cache.
so it works now.
